# How can i make python program to get executed in a loop in bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I have a  bash script where to execute the python program within  a loop as below. I see only once its getting executed with the below script. The echo statement prints all the filenames in the directory within the loop, whereas the pgm1.py executes only once. Kindly advice what i have to do it here to continuously getting executed for all the files with the directory.
Here is the below code.

```sh
LOG_DIR="directorypathname"
DT_H=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S'`
linkage_path="directoryname" 
yourfilenames=`ls $linkage_path`

for eachfile in $yourfilenames
do
    python3.5 ${CODE_DIR}/pgm1.py ${linkage_path}/${eachfile}  &> ${LOG_DIR}/${DT_H}.log
    echo ${linkage_path}/${eachfile}
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` to get lists of filenames](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use a shell wildcard instead: `for eachfile in "$linkage_path"/*; do ...` (but note that `$eachfile` will contain the directory as well as the filename, so just use `$eachfile`, not `${linkage_path}/${eachfile}`). There are a bunch of other minor problems with the script; run it through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), fix what it finds, and see if that makes it work. If not, add `set -x` before this section to get a trace of what's happening as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax wrong

```
for eachfile in $yourfilenames ; do
   python3.5 ${CODE_DIR}/pgm1.py ${linkage_path}/${eachfile} &>> \
      ${LOG_DIR}/${DT_H}.log
   echo ${linkage_path}/${eachfile}
   done
```

That should do the trick

Comment: i have used the above code also. I see the echo command gets executed multiple times. But the python program gets executed only once.

Comment: That's because you overwrite the same output file every time you run it.

Comment: True, I changed that in my solution